# how to get data from WebMethod in angular2

Tags: http, angular

In Javascript using Ajax

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: "AttendanceMaster.aspx/GetDistinctBatch",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "jsondata",
    async: "true",       
    success: function(response) {

    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert("(allstudent )" + response.status + ' Error ' + response.statusText);
    }
   });
```

tried following for angular2

```
  return this._http.get("AttendanceMast.apsx/GetDistinctBatch")
  .map((response) => response.toString());
```

it returns

```
{ "_isScalar": false, "source": { "_isScalar": false }, "operator": {} }
```

C#

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string GetDistinctBatch()
 {      
    return "welcome Angular 2";
 }
```

1) how to use in angular2?

See Error below

[image]

Comment: You have to `subscribe` over that method which is returning `Observable`, until then it would not work..

Comment: @ Pankaj Parkar  can you give me code what needs to be change in my code

Comment: .net project and angular2 on same application server?

Comment: yes both in same folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dataservice

```
getwithParamter(): Observable<JSON> {                

            this.headers = new Headers();
            this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');               

            let options = new RequestOptions({
                method: RequestMethod.Post,
                url: "AttendanceMast.aspx/HelloWorldss",                   
                headers: this.headers,
                body:{program: 'pravin'}  //same like data: "{}" in ajax
            });

           return this._http.request(new Request(options)).retry(2)
             .map((response: Response) => response.text())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);                  

    }
  handleError(error: any) {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

C#

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string HelloWorldss(string program)
{
    return "welcome Angular" + program;
}
```

call

```
  this.dataService.getwithParamter().subscribe(
        tradeshows => this.getwithparamter = tradeshows,
        error =>  console.error('Error: ' +error)
    );
```

print this  variable showing your output `this.getwithparamter`

Answer (score 5):

Your method is just returning `Observable`, they will just sit as a function. `Observable` are lazy in nature. They wouldn't get executed until you subscribe to them.

```
AttendanceMast() {
   return this._http.get("AttendanceMast.apsx/GetDistinctBatch")
         .map((response) => response.toString()); //better do it response.json();
}

myService.AttendanceMast().subscribe(
  data => console.log(data);
)
```

Comment: I searched but I got mostly using webapi Is it possible to use webmethod because it search path like url but its file name see in error

Comment: help me i totally blank

Comment: @Pravin error 404 meaning, route engine doesn't recognize it.

Comment: its normal **aspx** page and  business logic put in **aspx.cs**  so then how to call that in angular2  because it checks **url** instead of  **file**  so what to do because i am using normal  **.net project**  than  **mvc project**

Comment: Is there no way to access data from such condition ?

Comment: Are you able to access the URL and get the data in any other client like post man or in browser?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the standard configuration for a WebService. If so, I believe your problem is that your are using the inbuilt rest capability of Angular2 to access a WebService, aka a Soap service, returning xml soap envelopes. Hence the 404.

Unfortunately, you have a bit more work to do to make it work than if you were accessing a rest service.
Have a look at [angular2-soap](https://github.com/autopulous/angular2-soap) on github. It should get you on the right track.

Comment: thanks for reply but I got solution which already  given in  solution